# Ajax Control Toolkit Animation - Flip

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

The situation is very simple, I have two panel. In the event of OnMouseOver on the first panel. It will flip to show the second panel. I know the easiest way is to use the Jquery.
But I'm trying to learn and use the Ajax Control Toolkit Animation Extender.
Please point me into the right direction.

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Flip is not available in the animation reference of AnimationExtender.

- Animation
- Parent Animation
- Parallel Animation
- Sequence Animation
- Selection Animation
- Condition Animation
- Case Animation
- Fade Animation
- FadeIn Animation
- FadeOut Animation
- Pulse Animation
- Property Animation
- Discrete Animation
- Interpolated Animation
- Color Animation
- Length Animation
- Move Animation
- Resize Animation
- Scale Animation
- Action
- Enable Action
- Hide Action
- Style Action
- Opacity Action
- Script Action